# same database and query - production server is 100 times slower than local environment

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i am struggling to understand why production machine executes a query from PHPMYADMIN so slow compared to local machine.

The query I ran `to get the number of job each skill has`

```
SELECT jrs.skill_id, COUNT(jrs.job_id)
FROM
(
SELECT id
FROM job
WHERE active_to > NOW()
) as active_job
JOIN job_req_skill jrs 
WHERE jrt.job_id = active_job.id
GROUP BY skill_id
```

the database is exact the same on both production and local machine and no heavy traffic on the production server that takes away mysql resources.

Local server ( Win 7 with AMPPS , mysql ver 14.14 distrib 5.6.14 for win32 (x86), PhpMyAdmin v3.5.8.2)

- Query took **0.0780 sec**
- Exlain SQL ( http://pastebin.com/ucWxd6Pw )
- MySQL config  ( http://pastebin.com/hmz5f19z )

Production Server ( Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, mysql ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu, PhpMyAdmin v3.4.10.1)

- Query took **66.0930 sec**
- Exlain SQL ( http://pastebin.com/nJEW4TiF )
- MySQL config ( http://pastebin.com/Dn0BzZ1x )

Why is there such huge difference in performance ???

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the database is exactly the same? Do you have the same indexes set-up on the table, for example?

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?

Comment: @Duniyadnd on Linode 8GB plan (https://www.linode.com/pricing)

Comment: @dai yes , I downloaded production database and imported to local machine

Comment: @MichaelNguyen-HaTaDu how did you download the production database? Tools like phpMyAdmin might not necessarily save every detail about the database when exported.

Comment: @Dai in phpmyadmin, i clicked database name then export using default setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running MySQL version 5.5 in production, 5.6 locally. They obviously improved query optimizations in 5.6. Notice the different in the `EXPLAIN` output.

Try this:

```
SELECT jrs.skill_id, COUNT(*)
FROM job 
JOIN job_request_skill AS jrs ON jrs.job_id = job.id
WHERE job.active_to > NOW()
GROUP BY jrs.skill_id
```

Referring to the table directly, rather than in a subquery, may avoid constructing a temporary table. And you should generally use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(column)` unless you specifically need to avoid counting null values in the column; if there's an index on `skill_id`, it may then be able to use this to get the counts.

Comment: thanks, it does improve alot. Took 1.5s now. I also agree your assessment that the performance has to do with mysql v5.6 vs mysql v5.5

Comment: @MichaelNguyen-HaTaDu If that's the solution, you should mark the response as answered so other people know what response was the most useful instead of scrolling through each one.

Answer (score 1):

How many rows are you returning? It might be counting the time it takes to transmit the results from the host to your workstation.